# Highstock don't draw any

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have a function called data(), this function write with `echo $result."<br>";` this (data obtained from a database):

```
[20010426000000, 1],
[20010820000000, 1],
[20011201000000, 1],
[20020718000000, 1],
```

And i have the function to draw the highstock:

```
$(function() {
        // Create the chart
        $('#lineasAc').highcharts('StockChart', {
          ...
          name: 'Sales',
          data: [ 
            //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
          ],
        ...
```

If i put manually the result of the function works:

```
data: [        
  [20010426000000, 1],
  [20010820000000, 1],
  [20011201000000, 1],
  [20020718000000, 1],
],
```

But if i call the function don't work:

```
data: [ 
  <? echo data();?>
],
```

I tried to put the function inside the data without function and do `echo $result."<br>";`, also tried put `<?data();?>`, etc. Definitely i tried all of i know

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `json_encode()` for a cleaner JSON conversion.

Comment: i don't use json, is it really necessary?

Comment: It is not necessary, but could make your life easier. Currently your `data()` function produces something similar to JSON manually, which could be cleaner with `json_encode()`. As for your actual problem - you should include the necessary parts of the `data()` function as well.

Comment: If this won't be JSON, then it will be string or something strange. Sorry, but Highcharts requires JavaScript objects/arrays to work with them, it won't parse string into proper values.

Comment: Are those code segments from a .php file, or from a .js file ?

Comment: all is in the same .php file

Comment: Can you post the page source which is generated by the php ? Also post your data() function.

Comment: See realted topic http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i put this in the data:

```
  <?for ($i=1;$i<=$limit_acept;$i++){?>
       <?=$result[$i];?>
  <?}?>
```

I make a variable to asign to $result, and now with the bucle i print the data :)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be with your data() function. If it outputs 
 tags, then these will be included in your highcharts data, and won't be valid json. You should only echo the data:

```
echo $result;
```